# No electricity to half the house

Tags: electrical

Half of my house does not have any electricity even thou nothing has been plugged it to the outlets on that side of the house. What can I do to fix it.
Thank You
Terro

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. We'll need more information: is this a change? What is the situation with fuses/circuit breakers? Where are you located?

Comment: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/58725/why-is-half-of-my-house-without-power-with-no-flipped-breakers

Comment: about three years ago it did the same thing on the same side of the house. A friend changed a plug in and it came back in. This time nothing was plugged in at all on that side of the house.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are in North America, this probably indicates as problem in the main circuit breaker. Basically, you have two legs of 120V each with opposite phase so that when used together, you get 240V. Half of your 120V circuits are on one leg, the rest are on the other and 240V circuits (stove, furnace, etc.) are on both.

Probably one half of the main breaker isn't conducting. Try turning the main breaker off and on a few times to see if you can make it work.

Even if you get it working, you need to call an electrician to replace it.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the common issues of faulty wiring and main breakers, is the not so common problem of double pole fuses that have been retrofitted.

In smaller older homes a 240V appliance circuit normally in a kitchen is retrofitted into two small outlet / lighting circuits. Fuses that feed them go bad without any tell tell sign.

Using a digital meter, one can test each breaker by reading if voltage is being sent through them while in the on position, or for a fuse, first removing the fuse and reading if continuity passing through.